# nested JSON array to csv in PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I output this json to csv properly?

My json file pattern is like this:

```
{
"swimmers": [
{
  "Province": "Ontario",
  "Exemption": "S9,SB9,SM9",
  "Code": "A,3,4",
  "Level": "Level 8",
  "ClassificationDate": "2020",
  "RYEar": "2024",
  "Status": "Registered",
  "ID": "123456",
  "FirstName": "John",
  "LastName": "Doe",
  "Gender": "M",
  "AGE": null,
  "DOB": "01/11/2000",
  "Clubs": [
    {
      "Clubname": "Human Fish",
      "Code": "ABC",
      "Clubid": "300"
    }
  ],
  "Email": null,
  "Language": "E",
  "ChallengeData": null
}
 //more entries with same pattern as first
],
  "status": "OK",
  "application": "SOme App API"
}
```

I had success to turn it into a csv with the code below but I'm unable to output the clubs field in the csv file, instead of showing the club, it just shows  "Array()". I tried to fix that with the commented code but it doesn't solve the problem.

```
$csvFileName = 'converted.csv';
$json = 'myjson.json'; 
$data = file_get_contents($json); 
$payload= json_decode($data); 

$file_pointer = fopen($csvFileName, 'w');

if ($file_pointer){
    foreach($payload['swimmers'] as $row) {
        // $clubs = $row['Clubs'] ;
        // if (is_array($clubs)){
            // foreach($clubs as $c){
                // fputcsv($file_pointer, $c);
            // }
        // }else{
            fputcsv($file_pointer, $row);
        }
}
```

Comment: The Clubs field is an array of objects. How do you expect to show that in a single field of the CSV?

Comment: What should the CSV for this look like? How should it be if there's more than one club in the `Clubs` field?

Comment: province, exemptions.. etc are all columns and for clubs I want to ignore the "clubs" column and just add on to the columns clubname, code, clubid. SO basically I want all the keys to be columns and the values to be rows

Comment: But what if there's more than one club? Each row could have a different number of clubs.

Comment: Yeah I don't care about the Column name, I just care about just what's inside. So I want clubname, code, clubid to still be added on as columns

Comment: You already said that.

Comment: Yes there is more than 1 club. But the pattern is the same for the clubs.

Comment: Say there are 100 clubs. So, you want them one by one in new row each time? If yes, do you wish to copy other column values as well?

Comment: @nice_dev yes pretty much

Comment: @answerSeeker Ok, your first step should be to get the headers. You can do it manually but if the JSON keys change, you will have to redo the same thing again

Comment: Headers seems more complex than I thought it would be. The keys will never change, only the values change

Comment: @answerSeeker I agree but it is doable. However, you may need to know some concepts such as recursion.

Comment: Yeah, I'm beat for today. I'll sleep on it and try again tomorrow. THanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Append each element of the `Clubs` field to `$row`, then remove the `Clubs` field.

```
foreach ($payload['swimmers'] as $row) {
    foreach ($row['Clubs'] as $club) {
        $row = array_merge($row, array_values($club));
    }
    unset($row['Clubs']);
    fputcsv($file_pointer, $row);
}
```

Comment: Perfect!!! it works! one last thing, is there a way to have the headers as well, like province, exemptions etc at the top?

Comment: Yes. Before the loop, put `array_keys($payload['swimmers'])` in a variable `$headers`. Remove the `Clubs` element of the array, then use `fputcsv($file_pointer, $headers);`

Comment: You can also add the keys of the `Clubs` array to the `$headers` array. But you won't know how many of those headers to include, because it varies from row to row.

Comment: A CSV file should normally have the same number of fields in every row. Having a variable number of clubs is probably going to make processing it more difficult.

Comment: yes but clubname, code, clubid will remain static headers and they wont change

Comment: But there's a variable number of them.